# Angular service returning data only on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-services, angular4-forms

Why is `this.menulist` empty even after?

**layout.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {


    this.menulist = localStorage.getItem('menulist');  

    if (this.menulist) {

    } else {
      this.SetMenuList(); // Else call the service and sort the menu then
    }
     this.menulist = localStorage.getItem('menulist'); // null even after calling  SetMenulist
     this.jsonmenulist = JSON.parse(this.menulist); 
    } 

    SetMenuList() {
        this._UserspecificmenuaccessService.getRMA("driver")
      .map((lst) => {
        if (lst && lst.length > 0) {
          console.log(lst);
          localStorage.setItem('menulist', JSON.stringify(lst));
          this.menulist = localStorage.getItem('menulist'); this.jsonmenulist = JSON.parse(this.menulist);          

        }
      }, (error) => {
        console.error(error)
      });
  }
```

**Service method:**

```
  getRMA(Id:any): Observable<Imstmenu[]> {
     return this._http.get("http://172.19.32.235:3000/api/USMA/selectAll/"+Id+"")
    .map((response: Response) => {<Imstmenu[]>response.json(); 
    .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: You write the lst to log. What does it show?

Comment: `SetMenuList()` is an async function, when the line after runs it doesn't mean that `SetMenuList()` ended running.

Comment: @Programmer it just doesnt appear.. like execution flow never reached it.

Comment: @ibenjelloun what do I do then?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an `Observable` that gets the last value from local if available, else the server value after updating localstorage :

`updateMenuListOnce$` is an `Observable` that will call the server, updates localstorage and return the new value :

```
const updateMenuListOnce$ = 
  this._UserspecificmenuaccessService.getRMA("driver")
  .pipe(first(), 
   tap(menuList => localStorage.setItem('menulist', JSON.stringify(menuList)));
```

The `menuList$` `Observable` will return the value in localstorage if available, or subscribe to the previous declared `Observable` :

```
this.menuList$ = of(localStorage.getItem('menulist'))
.pipe(exhaustMap(menuList => 
   menuList ? of(<Imstmenu[]>menuList) : updateMenuListOnce$));
```

Now you just need to subscribe to the `menuList$` to get the menu list from localstorage if available or from the server.

Comment: `[ts]
Argument of type '(menuList: string) => Observable<Imstmenu[]> | Observable<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<Imstmenu[]>'.
  Type 'Observable<Imstmenu[]> | Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<Imstmenu[]>'.
    Type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<Imstmenu[]>'.
      Type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<Imstmenu[]>'.
        Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable<string>'.`

Comment: You just need to cast the `menuList` to `Imstmenu[]`, I edited the code.